# How to set no expiry for memc_set() function for mysql

Tags: mysql, memcached, mysql-5.1

I am new in MYSQL facing a problem in memcached UDF functions for MYSQL5.1. How can I set no expiry for `memc_set()` function? Because one data has been stored in memcached after some time it will displayed `NULL`.

Sample query here:

```
  SELECT id, name, ccode, createdat, updatedat,
  memc_set(concat('TEST:id:',id), id),
  memc_set(concat('TEST:name:',name), name),
  memc_set(concat('TEST:ccode:', ccode), ccode),
  memc_set(concat('TEST:createdat:', createdat), createdat),
  memc_set(concat('TEST:updatedat:', updatedat), updatedat)
  from test.CTEST;
```

Answer (score 0):

Memcached is [NOT a persistent datastore](http://code.google.com/p/memcached/wiki/NewOverview#Forgetting_Data_is_a_Feature). If you need one to behave somewhat similar, use a NoSQL DB.

Comment: How to set expiry time for memcached?

Comment: In mysql's memcached udf, I see no place to put the expiry in the official documentation. Probably it just isn't there, but if there is, it is probably the 2rd argument of the set command (seconds as integer).

Answer (score 0):

You may set the expiry as 0 value, which means no expire. But this won't guarantee your data won't be removed, it also depends on your memory allocated to memcached. It uses LRU approach to determine which data will be remove due to lack of memory.

Comment: Problem still there. Please have a look on below set and get script.

Comment: How to get date column from memcached. Because it displayed NULL when fetch date column from memcached.

Comment: I think date would be simply stored as string. I haven't give a try on memc UDF. I'm using libmemcached and pylibmc to work on my cases. How about trying store epoch time instead?

Comment: Hi Liu, Can you please give an example for Insert and Update trigger by which memcached will be updated accordingly. I have created an update trigger. But upon updation table it give error. ERROR 1123 (HY000): Can't initialize function 'memc_replace'; Usage: memc_replace('<key>', '<pair>', <optional: expiration>).

Comment: Hi there, I think if you want to update a key/value pair, you may simply memc_set(key, value, expire) again. You may write a script run at background and updating periodically. You don't know whether the key/value is expired or not until you query that key. If you get a cache miss, which means that key is no longer exist. Under this case, you should get a backup plan on database, updating the key/value inside your program.